# Vector of different specializations of a templated class

Tags: c++

Since I have been using templates in C++, I often encounter this problem: I would like to gather instances of different versions of a templated class in a vector.

I understand this is not possible directly, but I wonder if there is some workaround to achieve this.

For example if I have the templated class like so:

```
enum test_e
{
  TYPE_A,
  TYPE_B
};

template <test_e TYPE>
class test
{
  void doSomething()
  {
    switch (TYPE)
    {
      ...
    }
  }
};
```

I would like to build a vector where I could push both specializations (`TYPE_A` & `TYPE_B`) of the class `test`.

What's the best approach to do this?

Comment: Aside: why is `TYPE` a template parameter, if you only use it in a `switch`?

Comment: The same as for `class A` and `class B`.

Comment: inheritance, `std::variant`, `std::any`, (`std::function`?) are possible alternatives.

Comment: @Caleth cause I'm working on a project where I want max speed :)

Comment: That doesn't follow. `switch`ing on a template parameter doesn't magically undo the overhead of the type erasure that you'd need to have a heterogeneous vector. I think you'll find `TYPE` as a data member is *faster*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to store different template classes, you can make a parent class and inherit that class in the template class.

And I don't know why you're using `switch` for types, just use template instantiation.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

using std::cout;
using std::endl;


class Mother {
public:
    virtual void doSomeThing() = 0;
};

template<typename T>
class Child : public Mother {
    void doSomeThing() override;
};

template<typename T> void Child<T>::doSomeThing() {
    cout << "Base Function" << endl;
}
template<> void Child<int>::doSomeThing() {
    cout << "Int template" << endl;
}

template<> void Child<float>::doSomeThing() {
    cout << "Float template" << endl;
}

int main() {

    std::vector<std::unique_ptr<Mother>> vec;

    vec.emplace_back(new Child<double>());
    vec.emplace_back(new Child<int>());
    vec.emplace_back(new Child<float>());

    vec[0]->doSomeThing();
    vec[1]->doSomeThing();
    vec[2]->doSomeThing();


    return 0;
}
```

output:

```
Base Function
Int template
Float template

Process finished with exit code 0
```

Comment: Avoid raw owning pointers... `std::vector<std::unique_ptr<Mother>>` would avoid memleak.