# Implementing a class that uses a templated class without making original class a template

Tags: c++

Sorry if the title is confusing. Hopefully the example code will make it more clear.

Lets say I have a class:

```
template <typename T>
Class_A {
    //has some methods

}
```

Now I also have a class:

```
Class_B {

   vector<Class_A *> array;

   void add( Class_A * arg) {
       array.push_back(arg);
   }

}
```

So right now Class_B wouldn't work because I am not using like the T argument for my class_A arguments. My question is there a way to do this without making Class_B a template. Ideally the vector would be able to hold things like `Class_A<int>` and `Class_A<string>` so I really don't want Class_B templated.

Any ideas would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62061242/vector-of-different-specializations-of-a-templated-class/62062011#62062011 Does this answer to your question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Derive from `class A_Base` with destructor & relevant methods as `virtual`. Use this `A_Base`, wherever you don't want templates. E.g.

```
template<typename T>
class Class_A : public A_Base {
   ~Class_A() override; 
  // Other virtual methods
};
```

Answer (score 0):

The only way to do this without making `Class_B` a template would be to have the type be polymorphic; that is, have the template class `Class_A` inherit another class (say, `Class_A_base`) and store pointers to `Class_A_base` instead.

If you explain a bit more what you're trying to accomplish with this pattern, a better solution might be possible.