# How can I create a vector of derived objects?

Tags: c++, c++11, templates, inheritance, stl

I've read several posts on this website, but I still can't figure out what's the right way to create a `std::vector` of objects from different derived classes.

I've created a class `Column`:

```
template <typename T> class Column {
public:
    Column();
    virtual ~Column();
    vector<T>& getData();
    string getName();
    virtual string getType();

protected:
    string _name;
    vector<T> _data;
};
```

and many different derived classes like:

```
class IntColumn : public Column<int> {
public:

    IntColumn();
    IntColumn(string name);
    ~IntColumn();
    vector<int> & getData();
    void addElement(int elem_to_add);
    string getType();

private:
    // ...
};
```

What I need to do now is to create a vector of Columns which could be `IntColumn`s, `FloatColumn`s, etc...
(In my head it would be something like `vector<Column> vect;` but I can't do it because Column is a template class.)

My final question is: which is the right way to do it?

Comment: Keep a vector of pointers to a base class, and insert instances of derived class(es).

Comment: Are all the derived classes going to inherit from the same instantiation of `Column`, or can they be different?

Comment: You can have an ordinary class as a base class to Column. Put the virtual functions in the base class to Column.

Comment: You can't create a vector of different objects, that's simply not the way C++ works.  You can only have a vector of pointers to the base class as @Ron points out.

Comment: does this answer your question? [Vector of different specializations of a templated class](https://stackoverflow.com/q/62061242/8176989)

Comment: @cigien Pardon my ignorance, I'm not sure I understood what you meant.
I want the vector to contain various "types" of column...

Comment: I'm referring to your design. Perhaps you might want to look at template specializations instead of derived classes.

Comment: @김선달 It's a similar problem I think, but I'm really struggling to understand this topic

Comment: So I should do something like vector<unique_ptr<Column>> vect;?

Comment: @Ron If I type vector<unique_ptr<Column>> it keeps saying "Use of class template 'Column' requires template arguments"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, you're missing a base class. `Column` is a template, not a class, and having virtual methods inside a template is rarely useful.

```
class Column {
public:
    Column();
    virtual ~Column() {}
    std::string getName() const { return _name; }
    virtual std::string getType();

protected:
    std::string _name;
};

template <typename T> class ColumnImpl : public Column {
public:
    ColumnImpl();
    std::vector<T>& getData() { return _data; }
    std::vector<T> const& getData() const { return _data; }

protected:
    std::vector<T> _data;
};
```

*Now* you can do

```
std::vector<std::unique_ptr<Column>> vec;
```

to store (owning) pointers to `Column` instances.

Comment: Thank you very much!

Now I have 3 more questions:

- Would it be more "correct" and neat creating a new header file for ColumnImpl?
- I didn't understand why I need to create a new class, why is my Column a template, instead of a class? (You can link me to a site to understand the difference)
- Why didn't you put the virtual methods into ColumnImpl?

Comment: Then should I inherit all the `IntColumn`, `FloatColumn`, `CharColumn`, etc. classes from `ColumnImpl`?

Comment: It is unclear what the end goal is so cannot really advise further. `IntColumn` could be simply `typedef`'d to `ColumnImpl<int>`.

Comment: I'm using this for a homework I was given by my professor (He's totally not open to question unfortunately). The final goal is to create a program that "emulates" SQL language, so I'm trying to create a Table which consists of different `Column`s  so that every time I have to add a record I will add elements to my vectors `_data`...

Answer (score 0):

Vectors, like all other standard containers are homogeneous. All elements of the container are of same type. As such, one element cannot be of different type than another. All elements of one vector can be `IntColumns` or all elements of another vector can be `FloatColumns`, but you cannot mix and match different element types in one vector.

This problem can be solved with the magic of indirection. There are a few alternatives:

1. Use a vector of pointer to a common base. This way the vector doesn't contain the objects, but instead the contained pointers point to objects elsewhere. You can bind the lifetime of the pointed object to the pointer by using a smart pointer such as `std::unique_ptr`.

   However, this only works when different types have a common base. But your classes do not have a common base.
2. Use a vector of tagged union such as `std::variant`. This approach does not require inheritance, but is limited to finite set of alternative types.
3. Use unconstrained type erasure such as vector of `void*` or `std::any`. This allows the pointed elements to have any object type, but there is not much that can be done with the objects. I haven't encountered practical use cases for this.

Comment: So if I want to have more than 3 types and also keep my Column class as a template class, there's no solution, am I right?

Comment: @JohnBardeen A solution is to add a common base.